# sql query to get celing value. eg: 87/20 i should get 5

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
count=87;

select celing(4.35) from tablename;
o/p=5
select celing(count(*)/20) from tablename;
o/p=4
select celing(87/20) from tablename;
o/p=4
```

Required o/p should be 5 when i'm executing this query

```
 (select celing(count(*)/20) from tablename;)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  So, ceiling is not necessary.  You can do:

```
select celing(count(*)/20.0) from tablename;

select celing(87/20.0) from tablename;
```

That is, the division returns `4` as an integer, because that is how the division works.  The ceiling of this value is still `4`.  You need to do the division as a decimal number.